# How to produce numbers in some step bounds?

Tags: math, numbers

I want to produce numbers with some steps,
for example for step 4, i want to produce:

```
1   -> 0
3   -> 4
4.1 -> 4
15  -> 16
etc.
```

for step 0.2:

```
1     -> 1
3     -> 3
4.1   -> 4.2
15.99 -> 16
etc.
```

Do you know nice formula to produce numbers like these?

Comment: It looks like you just want to `round` to the nearest multiple of `step`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you just want to `round()` to the nearest multiple of `step`. Try this:

`result = round(num/step)*step`

#### Step 4:

- round(1/4)*4=0*4=0
- round(3/4)*4=1*4=4
- round(4.1/4)*4=1*4=4
- round(15/4)*4=4*4=16

#### Step 0.2:

- round(1/0.2)*0.2=5*0.2=1
- round(3/0.2)*0.2=15*0.2=3
- round(4.1/0.2)*0.2=21*0.2=4.2
- round(15.99/0.2)*4=80*0.2=16